# Is it possible get around C# function parameter strong typing?

Tags: c#, strong-typing

I have a C# application using ADO.Net access to a particular type of database (VistaDB) which I need to extend to optionally use a second type of database (SQL Server).

I'm unable to use Vista Entity Framework data access (which can support multiple database types) as this requires a higher version of the .NET framework than is available to most of my users. My data access functions take VistaDBConnection as ref arguments and whilst I can overload the functions to provide SqlConnection argument support, this will mean replicating a large number of data access functions.

I was wondering if it was possible to define function arguments to be either VistaDBConnection or SqlConnection types and then test for which type has been passed and provide options inside the data access routine to use either. I can do this by passing both VistaConnection and SqlConnection arguments to the data access functions but passing a single argument or variable type would be neater. However, this does break the strong typing feature of C#.

Answer (score 2):

The best would be either to create an interface or a base class. Then have two concrete classes that implement this interface, one for VistaDB and one for SQL Server. You can then use some kind of factory (or Dependency Injection) to instantiate the correct class at runtime. The methods in question would then take an instance of the interface/base class and does not need to know any of the specific inner workings. For example:

```
interface IApplicationDatabase
{
    Foo GetFoo(int id);
}

class VistaDatabase : IApplicationDatabase
{
    public Foo GetFoo(int id)
    {
        //do VistaDB-specific things to get the Foo
    }
}

class SqlServerDatabase : IApplicationDatabase
{
    public Foo GetFoo(int id)
    {
        //do SQL Server-specific things to get the Foo
    }
}

class Demo
{
    public Foo GetFooFromStorage(int id, IApplicationDatabase storage)
    {
        //notice here we don't need any separate code depending on the
        //concrete type of database
        return storage.GetFoo(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define more generic type or we can say parent type of the both connection SQL as well as VistaDB connection like following. and then use as operator to cast and check against null to check whether cast was successful or not.

```
public void Connect(DbConnection dbConnection)
{
    var sqlDbCon = dbConnection as SQLConnection;
    if(con != null)
    {
       //process here for SQLConnection
    }

    var vistaDbCon = dbConnection as VistaDbConnection;
    if(con != null)
    {
       //process here for VistaDbConnection
    }

}
```

You don't need to do separate implementation in if else if all you want is available in a parent class like in this case if you just want to call connect method then you can do it like below because it does have connect method in IDbConnection.

```
public void Connect(IDbConnection dbConnection)
{
    dbConnection.Open();
}
```

It would work in both the case with sql server and vistadb.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, Instead of using a class as type for the parameter, use interface as type for the parameter. 
This interface will be defined by you and implemented individually for each type of connection.
Now when you pass instance of any classes implementing the interface, your code will work.

Use Interface function to call provider specific functions.

Previous two code samples added by other contributors is the correct example for that, Use any of them.